# Is it possible to hide a column in an asp:repeater?

Tags: asp.net

I need to hide a column in an `asp:repeater`.  Preferably, hide them server side not just in HTML via CSS.  The repeater has an `ID`, but I am having difficulty finding the table that it owns within the debugger.  Considering how a repeater works I'm not sure its even possible.  I gave the HTML `table` an `ID` and set it to `runat="server"`, but it blew up with error

> Unexpected end of file looking for
>   tag.

How can I do it?  Do I need to switch to a gridview?  I could probably do this a lot easier with a gridview.

```
<asp:repeater id="repeaterId" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col1")%></td>
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col2")%></font></td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>                                                   <tr>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col1")%></td>
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col2")%></td> 
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="rPhysicalTable" class="cssTable">
                            <tr class="aClass">
                                <th>col1</th>
                                <th>col2</th>   
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:repeater>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide a column"? A repeater has no columns, it just emits content for each item it's bound to.

Comment: If you want to use the Repeater as a Table you should really consider to use a GridView.

Comment: @Joel C Right, thats what I meant by "considering how a repeater works".  Sorry that I was not more clear.  @Tim Schmelter - I agree.  The repeater doesn't seem like a good fit.  I am going to switch to a gridview.  If you want to move your comment to an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Tim Schmelter's advice I switched to a gridview.  This way I can use

```
gridviewObj.Columns[index].Visible = false;
```

And thus avoid hiding multiple `<td>` in a repeater.

Answer (score 12):

We can hide the column of a html table using the repeaters ItemDataBound event

To do this, we specify the id for the table cells to be hidden and tag the cell as runat="server"

```
<asp:repeater id="repeaterId" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="tdhideItem" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col1")%></td>
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col2")%></font></td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>                                                   <tr>
                            <td id="tdhideAltItem" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col1")%></td>
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col2")%></td> 
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="rPhysicalTable" class="cssTable">
                            <tr class="aClass">
                                <th id="thhideHeader" runat="server">col1</th>
                                <th>col2</th>   
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:repeater>
```

The following vb.net code is specified as code behind

```
  Protected Sub repeaterId_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repeaterId.ItemDataBound

         If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item  Then
        DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tdhideItem"), HtmlTableCell).Visible = False    
        End If

         If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem
        Then
        DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tdhideAltItem"), HtmlTableCell).Visible = False    
        End If

      If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then
        DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("thhideHeader"), HtmlTableCell).Visible = False    
        End If
        End Sub
```

In the above code the first column of the table "col1"  is set to be hidden

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ItemDataBound` event of `Repeater` in this event you can hide any row or column according to your requirements. Here is a MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) 
In this event you can use `FindControl` method to find your control and set its `Visible` property false.

```
e.Row.FindControl("ControlID");
```

Comment: There's not really a single column to deal with.  The table has the header, alternatingitemtemplate and item template to deal with.  I'm going to switch to a gridview.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: if you want to use [AlternatingItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) you can use it in repeater control. If you want Edit Update Delete kind of functionality then you should use Gridview but if you want to show only data then you can use Repeater. Anyway choice is yours.

Comment: The reason I like gridview in this case is because I can do `gridviewObj.Columns[5].Visible = false;`.  I cant do this so easily with a repeater.  Even if I use `Row.FindControl`, there's no single control to find.  I'll need to ID several `<td>` and hide each one.

Answer (score -1):

Hide a column in repeater control in the following way:

ItemDataBound Even of repearter use the following code

```
HtmlTableCell tdTableCell = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdTableCell");
tdTableCell.Visible = False;
```

In the front pade inside the reaper table cell should be as follows

```
<td id="tdTableCell" runat="server"></td>
```

Also hide the header cell by providing it id & Runat in the html and `visible = false` in page load.

You should use the following Usings:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

This way I have been able to hide column in repeater control.