# display and hide particular column in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a repeater. And i want to hide and display a particular column for a particular condition. I have three types of subjects and their ids are 0,1,2 respectively. Now i want to show that particular column when the subject will be 2 only..

My code is :-

```
 <table id="table1" class="yui" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <a href='#' title="Click Header to Sort">EmpID #</a>
                        </th>
<th>Edit</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repaddressorbbl" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repaddressorbbl_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <tr id="gh" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select(this);">
                                <td style="text-align: center;">
                                    <%#Eval("empid")%>
                                </td>  
 <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lknumber" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="subjectid" />
                                </td>                             
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>

                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051483/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-column-in-an-asprepeater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should start by using `<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>` and `<FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>` to define the start and end of your table just to tidy it up.

You can get the table to run on the server by adding a runat="server" and give the column `<td>` an id and a runat="server" attribute so you can program server code against it. I'd then eval bind the visible attribute of the cell based on your field value or use attributes.add("display:none") or just use a grid view as suggested in the link.

Answer (score 4):

You could catch the OnItemDataBound event of the repeater and hide the column there if the (subject) item id is 2.

In order you can get a reference to the column, make it a server control:

```
<td style="text-align: center;" id="COL_TO_HIDE" runat="server"><%#Eval("empid")%></td>
```

Then in the repeater event you can simply look for the control and hide it:

```
protected void YourRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var subject = (Subject)e.Item.DataItem;
        if (subject.Id == 2)
        {
            var col = e.Item.FindControl("COL_TO_HIDE");
            col.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, this is just a simplified example which should you get started.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repaddressorbbl" runat="server" 
OnItemCommand="Repaddressorbbl_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="gh" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select(this);">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <%#Eval("empid")%>
            </td>  
            <% if (false){ %>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lknumber" runat="server" 
                 Text="Edit" CommandName="subjectid" />
            </td> 
            <% } %>                             
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```